# Parsing Soap request in XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am trying to get the values out of the Soap request I made. It comes in an XML format, for some reason I cant get just the values. How can I? How would I get just maximum and minimum temperature values?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WeatherData.Weather_Gov;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WeatherData
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ndfdXMLPortTypeClient client = new ndfdXMLPortTypeClient();


            weatherParametersType weatherParams = new weatherParametersType();

            string weatherData;

            decimal lat = (decimal)(31.5452);
            decimal lon = (decimal)-109.468;

            weatherData = client.NDFDgenByDay(lat, lon, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(-1), "2", "e", "12 hourly");

            var myElement = XElement.Parse(weatherData);

            Console.WriteLine(weatherData);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the **output** what I got in my console application window.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwml version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/20
01/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/DWML
gen/schema/DWML.xsd">
  <head>
    <product srsName="WGS 1984" concise-name="dwmlByDay" operational-mode="official">
      <title>NOAA's National Weather Service Forecast by 12 Hour Period</title>
      <field>meteorological</field>
      <category>forecast</category>
      <creation-date refresh-frequency="PT1H">2015-06-01T15:16:52Z</creation-date>
    </product>
    <source>
      <more-information>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/</more-information>
      <production-center>Meteorological Development Laboratory<sub-center>Product Generation Bra
nch</sub-center></production-center>
      <disclaimer>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/disclaimer.html</disclaimer>
      <credit>http://www.weather.gov/</credit>
      <credit-logo>http://www.weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</credit-logo>
      <feedback>http://www.weather.gov/feedback.php</feedback>
    </source>
  </head>
  <data>
    <location>
      <location-key>point1</location-key>
      <point latitude="31.55" longitude="-109.47"/>
    </location>
    <moreWeatherInformation applicable-location="point1">http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.ph
p?textField1=31.55&amp;textField2=-109.47</moreWeatherInformation>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="12hourly">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n1-1</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time period-name="Today">2015-06-01T06:00:00-07:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2015-06-01T18:00:00-07:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="12hourly">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n1-2</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time period-name="Tonight">2015-06-01T18:00:00-07:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2015-06-02T06:00:00-07:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="12hourly">
      <layout-key>k-p12h-n2-3</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time period-name="Today">2015-06-01T06:00:00-07:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2015-06-01T18:00:00-07:00</end-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time period-name="Tonight">2015-06-01T18:00:00-07:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2015-06-02T06:00:00-07:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="12hourly">
      <layout-key>k-p1d-n1-4</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2015-06-01T06:00:00-07:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2015-06-02T06:00:00-07:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <parameters applicable-location="point1">
      <temperature type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-1">
        <name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
        <value>94</value>
      </temperature>
      <temperature type="minimum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-2">
        <name>Daily Minimum Temperature</name>
        <value>58</value>
      </temperature>
      <probability-of-precipitation type="12 hour" units="percent" time-layout="k-p12h-n2-3">
        <name>12 Hourly Probability of Precipitation</name>
        <value>4</value>
        <value>2</value>
      </probability-of-precipitation>
      <weather time-layout="k-p12h-n2-3">
        <name>Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity</name>
        <weather-conditions weather-summary="Mostly Sunny"/>
        <weather-conditions weather-summary="Mostly Clear"/>
      </weather>
      <conditions-icon type="forecast-NWS" time-layout="k-p12h-n2-3">
        <name>Conditions Icons</name>
        <icon-link>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/few.jpg</icon-link>
        <icon-link>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/nfew.jpg</icon-link>
      </conditions-icon>
      <hazards time-layout="k-p1d-n1-4">
        <name>Watches, Warnings, and Advisories</name>
        <hazard-conditions xsi:nil="true"/>
      </hazards>
    </parameters>
  </data>
</dwml>
```

How **do I pull out, for example, the Daily Max Temp**?

```
  <temperature type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-1">
      <name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
      <value>94</value>
  </temperature>
```

Comment: Juan9 - it might be easier if you just break the output and input into two boxes so it is more obvious to people trying to help. And make it clear you want to get to Daily Minimum Temperature = 58. There is a bit too much detail here.

Comment: I tried, but I need more reputation points to have them split.

Comment: Ok I will edit for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So once you've parsed your XML to an `XElement`, you use the LINQ to XML API to query it:

```
var max = element.Descendants("temperature")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Element("name") == "Daily Maximum Temperature")
    .Select(e => (int)e.Element("value"))
    .Single();

var min = element.Descendants("temperature")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Element("name") == "Daily Minimum Temperature")
    .Select(e => (int)e.Element("value"))
    .Single();
```

If you had multiple values, then you could iterate through a sequence of integers:

```
var maxTemps = element.Descendants("temperature")
    .Where(e => (string) e.Element("name") == "Daily Maximum Temperature")
    .SelectMany(e => e.Elements("value"))
    .Select(e => (int)e);
```

Comment: What if I have 2 values in Daily Maximum Temperature? I tried a foreach and It only gives me the first value.

Comment: @Juan9 added an option for that.